# TSQL Reinsert deleted row w/ a PK

Tags: t-sql, row, primary-key, restore

[just sharing...] Long time ago DB had no reference constraints and someone hard-deleted a staff person from PK-autoincrementing table that would not allow PK turned off. Orphaned a bunch of data, and I had to reinsert the row with the former PK value. DB does not allow table structure changes but allows renaming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what you mean by auto-incrementing or why it doesn't allow 'PK Turn off', we can't really pose a different solution.

If by auto-incrementing you mean IDENTITY, then you can use `SET IDENTITY_INSERT OFF` to allow explicit insertion of identity values.

Comment: This situation involves a legacy system so I don't know the underlying settings. When I use Design and on the PK identity column try to change the Identity Specification (Is Identity) from Yes to No, the DB precludes Save with the notation: `Saving changes is not permitted. The changes you have made require the following tables to be dropped and re-created or enabled [sic] the option Prevent saving changes that require the table to be re-created.` and it lists the table I just tried to modify

Comment: In the query window in SSMS, type `SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable ON`. You will now be allowed to update and insert values in your identity column. When your done, type `SET IDENTITY_INSERT YourTable OFF` and the field will autoincrement again. This is not a particular database setting, it's a command that you issue. You definitely can't do anything from the design pane. Why don't you do some research and provide more info then we can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I did:

```
/****
create protoTable w/ same structure as your mainTable that has the data you are trying to fix in this example the fieldname of the primary key is FldPK
assumption here is that your primary key is getting auto incremented
get a list of the fields in the mainTable that are NOT NULL.
in this example those fields are <not null fields>
get a list of all fields in the mainTable
in this example <all fields>, rather than spell out the fields. DO NOT INCLUDE the primary key field name
***/
declare @x int, @y int, @iLast int
select @iLast = (select MAX( FldPK ) from mainTable)
set @x = 1
while @x <= @iLast
begin
  select @y = (select COUNT(*) from mainTable where FldPK = @x)
  if @y = 1
    begin
      insert into protoTable(<all fields>)
        select <all fields> from mainTable where FldPK = @x
    end
  else
    begin
      insert into protoTable (<not null fields> )values('N','xyz'+convert(varchar,@x)) /*or whatever values are valid to fulfill not null*/
      /* this is where you keep one or more of the missing rows to update later with the lost data */
      if @x <> 126
        begin
          delete protoTable where FldPK = @x
        end
    end
  set @x=@x+1
end
```

Then renamed mainTable for archive and protoTable to mainTable. If anyone has a slicker way of doing this I'd love to see it.